# Is Visual Studio Team System Database Edition stable?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am trying to find out if it is worth moving to this system, and would like to know people's experiences with it?

Have you found it to be stable? Buggy?

What are some of the issues you have had with it?

Comment: Your original question was far too argumentative.

Comment: Okay.. It wasn't meant to be, but thanks!

Comment: @jdharley: No problem, I know how it goes sometimes, just figured we could ask the same thing in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It is the only way to have SQL Server 2005 database projects in VS 2008, as far as I know. I have not noticed anything wrong with it.